# ROS and Gazebo answers Migration

Tags: app

### ROS and Gazebo migration

We are migrating [rosanswers](https://answers.ros.org/questions/) and [gazeboanswers](https://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/) to the [Robotics Stack Exchange site](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/). We are using the Stack Exchange API through this app.

### Contact

If you have any doubts or questions please write us to: answers-se-migration@openrobotics.org

##### Logos

[image: Gazeboanswers]

[image: Rosanswers]

Comment: Welcome to the network! I'd recommend to discuss on [their Meta site](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/) whether and on which terms they'd want a mass migration of Q&As.